# Jenkins: manually adjust job execution order in queue

Tags: jenkins, queue

Is there any Jenkins plugin providing possibility to adjust job execution sequence in queue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Even if it's late but if somebody else came across:

See this plugin:

- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Accelerated+Build+Now+Plugin
- You can not tell an order but bring your manually started job to the top of the queue.

Not meeting your question 100% but there is also an issue filed to bring your job to the top of the queue:

- See also: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-1878

Comment: I have some serious doubts that a plugin with last release in 2013 will work with current version of Jekins (2018), especially with various types of pipeline ones.

Comment: Also worth noting that the plugin will try to kill a random build that wasn't triggered by a human in order to get the new job to run.

Comment: It is up for adoption , no changes since [2013 per above]. One person in 2017 got an exception. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Accelerated+Build+Now+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

There are **[plugins to adjust the priority](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Priority+Sorter+Plugin)** of jobs, but I haven't heard of anything that allows you to move the position in queue on demand.